# Can I obtain British/Swedish citizenship via grandparents?

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, citizenship, sweden, naturalization

Grandfather was Swedish, grandmother was British. They moved to Canada and got married in Canada and had my Dad. They divorced and grandmother moved back to UK. Unfortunately my own deceased parents were not married when they had me.

I am pretty sure UK and Sweden don't allow for citizenship via ancestry like Germany allows.

So if not by ancestry, if I track down my grandmother's (UK )or grandfather's (Swedish) birth certificates and Canadian marriage certificate, is it possible to get citizenship that way even though my own parents have already died?

===

Can a deceased person become a naturalized British/Swedish citizen?

If my deceased father's parents were Swedish/British is it possible to get citizenship for him even though he's deceased? Technically it's just paperwork right? I'm asking because then I could get it through him

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but given your chain of ancestry you have given, I think it's unlikely (as citizenship by descent only survives one generation) but possible - https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent

Comment: Thanks. Please see updated question.

Comment: Even if it were possible to grant a dead person citizenship from a third party application, you would still run into the issues for the UK I noted above - it's almost certain that the citizenship eligibility would not survive the double descendant hop from grandparent to parent to you.

Comment: It is quite common in nationality law for the child of an unmarried couple *not* to get the nationality of the father.  A cursory reading of the Wikipedia article on Swedish nationality law suggests that your father may have been Swedish when you were born (depending on his age at the time), but even if he was you would only have been Swedish if your parents had been married or if you had been born in Sweden. British citizenship law has changed a lot over the years so it's impossible to say without knowing the dates.

Comment: Hi Phoog. My father might have been a Swedish citizen correct. And yes my parents were not married so I guess that rules me out like you said. I was born in 45 so the rules were a lot stricter then.

Comment: If you were born in 1945, and your father had not already applied for and received British citizenship prior to your birth OR had received citizenship by way of his parents, then you are not eligible for it - https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent/born-before-1983 Sorry!

Comment: Yeah I found that out. I was also trying to get info on Sweden too but the laws back then are so strict compared with today. Today the parents don't even have to be married. So easy.